# Find the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{1}{a_1a_2}+\frac{1}{a_2a_3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_na_{n-1}}$

Tags: limits

> Given $a_1=1$ and $a_n=a_{n-1}+4$ where $n\geq2$ calculate,
>   $$\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{1}{a_1a_2}+\frac{1}{a_2a_3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_na_{n-1}}$$

First I calculated few terms $a_1=1$, $a_2=5$, $a_3=9,a_4=13$ etc. So 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{1}{a_1a_2}+\frac{1}{a_2a_3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_na_{n-1}}=\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{5\times9}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_na_{n-1}}
$$

Now I got stuck. How to proceed further? Should I calculate the sum ? Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT:

$$\dfrac4{a_ma_{m-1}}=\dfrac{a_m-a_{m-1}}{a_ma_{m-1}}=?$$

$a_m=1+4\cdot(m-1)=?$

Do you recognize the [Telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)?

Comment: So I did, $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{4}(\frac{1}{a_1}-\frac{1}{a_2}+\frac{1}{a_2}-\frac{1}{a_3}+\cdots +\frac{1}{a_n-1}-\frac{1}{a_n})$, so the series telescopes.

Answer (score 2):

As lab bhattacharjee mentioned for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we have 
$$a_n-a_{n-1}=4$$
$$\begin{align}
  & {{I}_{n}}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}{\frac{1}{{{a}_{i}}{{a}_{i+1}}}}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}{\frac{1}{{{a}_{i+1}}-{{a}_{i}}}\left( \frac{1}{{{a}_{i}}}-\frac{1}{{{a}_{i+1}}} \right)}=\frac{1}{4}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}{\left( \frac{1}{{{a}_{i}}}-\frac{1}{{{a}_{i+1}}} \right)}=\frac{1}{4}\left( \frac{1}{{{a}_{i}}}-\frac{1}{{{a}_{n}}} \right) \\ 
 & {{I}_{n}}=\frac{1}{4}\left( \frac{1}{{{a}_{1}}}-\frac{1}{{{a}_{1}}+4n-4} \right) \\ 
\end{align}
$$
therefore
$$\underset{n\to \infty }{\mathop{\lim }}\,{{I}_{n}}=\frac{1}{4{{a}_{1}}}=\frac{1}{4}$$